# Using an iterator as an argument to a function multiple times from one vector

Tags: rust, iterator, ownership

I'm trying to write some Rust code to decode GPS data from an SDR receiver.  I'm reading samples in from a file and converting the binary data to a series of complex numbers, which is a time-consuming process.  However, there are times when I want to stream samples in without keeping them in memory (e.g. one very large file processed only one way or samples directly from the receiver) and other times when I want to keep the whole data set in memory (e.g. one small file processed in multiple different ways) to avoid repeating the work of parsing the binary file.

Therefore, I want to write functions or structs with iterators to be as general as possible, but I know they aren't sized, so I need to put them in a `Box`.  I would have expected something like this to work.

This is the simplest example I could come up with to demonstrate the same basic problem.

```
fn sum_squares_plus(iter: Box<Iterator<Item = usize>>, x: usize) -> usize {
    let mut ans: usize = 0;
    for i in iter {
        ans += i * i;
    }
    ans + x
}

fn main() {
    // Pretend this is an expensive operation that I don't want to repeat five times
    let small_data: Vec<usize> = (0..10).collect();

    for x in 0..5 {
        // Want to iterate over immutable references to the elements of small_data
        let iterbox: Box<Iterator<Item = usize>> = Box::new(small_data.iter());
        println!("{}: {}", x, sum_squares_plus(iterbox, x));
    }

    // 0..100 is more than 0..10 and I'm only using it once,
    // so I want to 'stream' it instead of storing it all in memory
    let x = 55;
    println!("{}: {}", x, sum_squares_plus(Box::new(0..100), x));
}
```

I've tried several different variants of this, but none seem to work.  In this particular case, I'm getting

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<std::slice::Iter<'_, usize> as std::iter::Iterator>::Item == usize`
  --> src/main.rs:15:52
   |
15 |         let iterbox: Box<Iterator<Item = usize>> = Box::new(small_data.iter());
   |                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected reference, found usize
   |
   = note: expected type `&usize`
              found type `usize`
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn std::iter::Iterator<Item = usize>`
```

I'm not worried about concurrency and I'd be happy to just get it working sequentially on a single thread, but a concurrent solution would be a nice bonus.

Comment: Why are you passing a `Box<T>` and not just `&T` in your functions? Do you want multiple references to your iterators? If you want to pass a flow of data between threads / tasks, did you consider `std::collections::VecDeque` which can be fed from one end and drained from another? I'm just trying to understand your design considerations.

Comment: I'm using a `Box<T>` because it implements `Sized` and I want to be able to use it in structs.  In the first case, I want to have one master copy of the data in a `Vec` and create iterators over immutable references to the elements.  I don't want to use `VecDeque` because I don't want to drain it on the receiving end.  I also don't want to just pass immutable references to the `Vec` because I also want to be able to stream samples into the consumer without storing them in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current error you're running into is here:

```rust
let iterbox:Box<Iterator<Item = usize>> = Box::new(small_data.iter());
```

You're declaring that you want an iterator that returns `usize` items, but `small_data.iter()` is an iterator that returns references to `usize` items (`&usize`). That why you get the error "expected reference, found usize". `usize` is a small type that's cloneable so you can simply use the `.cloned()` iterator adapter to provide an iterator that actually returns a usize.

```rust
let iterbox: Box<Iterator<Item = usize>> = Box::new(small_data.iter().cloned());
```

Once you're past that hurdle, the next problem is that the iterator returned over `small_data` contains a reference to the `small_data`. Since `sum_squares_plus` is defined to accept a `Box<Iterator<Item = usize>>`, it's implied in that signature that the `Iterator` trait object within the box has a `'static` lifetime. The iterator you're providing does not because it borrows `small_data`. To fix that you need to adjust the `sum_squares_plus` definition to

```rust
fn sum_squares_plus<'a>(iter: Box<Iterator<Item = usize> + 'a>, x: usize) -> usize
```

Note the `'a` lifetime annotations. The code should then compile, but unless there's some constraints other than what's clearly defined here, a more idiomatic and efficient approach would be to avoid using trait objects and the associated allocations. The below code should work using static dispatch without any trait objects.

```rust
fn sum_squares_plus<I: Iterator<Item = usize>>(iter: I, x: usize) -> usize {
    let mut ans: usize = 0;
    for i in iter {
        ans += i * i;
    }
    ans + x
}

fn main() {
    // Pretend this is an expensive operation that I don't want to repeat five times
    let small_data: Vec<usize> = (0..10).collect();

    for x in 0..5 {
        println!("{}: {}", x, sum_squares_plus(small_data.iter().cloned(), x));
    }

    // 0..100 is more than 0..10 and I'm only using it once,
    // so I want to 'stream' it instead of storing it all in memory
    let x = 55;
    println!("{}: {}", x, sum_squares_plus(Box::new(0..100), x));
}
```